# How to sync the data structure of my iPod touch with that of my iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, ipod-touch, data-synchronization

I have two device: iPod touch and iPad. All of them use the newest OS.

I have a folder in my Windows, call it c:\mybook.
I put all my pdf books into this folder. No nested categorizing folder for sure.

I import these books from iTune using CTRL+O (add file to library). Then I sync my iPod touch.
From within iPod touch, I make collections based on genres such as Physics, Math, Biology, etc. I move each book to the proper collection. All books have been arranged and I am happy.

Next... how to make the arrangement in iPod to be reflected to my iPad? Hopely using the simplest method. For sure, my iPad has been restored to default factory without any data now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sync your iPod Touch configuration back to iTunes and then sync your iPad with iTunes!

For syncing your iPod configuratuon you must only connect it with iTunes. Every time it will be created a backup of the device. After that you connect your iPad (which has been restored to default factory) with iTunes.

Then you can do the following steps which are described on the [apple support sites](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) (Restoring your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch).

Comment: @Tim Kruger, How to sync ipod config to iTunes? Sorry I am a newbie. :-)

Comment: @Tim, How to sync my ipod config BACK to iTunes?

Comment: @xport: I'm a little bit confused. Will you sync the complete iPod Touch configuration or only the iBook configuration or both?

Comment: @Tim, complete is preferred.

Comment: @xport: I edited my answer!